# How to make random css animation time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

Im now doing project Google Dino, and I want to make a random cactus animation time and delay but I dont know how, here is my code:

```
`.cactus-anim {
    animation: cactus-move 1.3s 0.5s linear infinite;

}

@keyframes cactus-move {
    0% {
        left: 700px;
    }

    100% {
        left: -40px;
    }
}`
```

(I want to make instead of 1.3s - random(1-2)s, and instead of 0.5s - random(0-0.7)s , and also Im using Scss and Js, Thnks

Comment: As of now this cannot be solved with CSS or SASS only as CSS doesn't have a random number generator and SASS random numbers are set to a random, but afterwards static number on build. For a solution involving JS, this is a good place to start: https://css-tricks.com/random-numbers-css/

Answer (score 3):

You could add this code to your JS, and run it whenever you need to randomize the animation time, but this is not possible in plain CSS.

```
const anim = document.querySelector(".cactus-anim");

// gets a random number between 2 values
function randNum(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}

// run this function to set a new, random animation time
function randAnimTime() {
    // sets the new animation time
    // first time random is between 1 and 2 seconds
    // second is random between 0 and 0.7 seconds
    anim.style.animation = "cactus-move " + randNum(1, 2) + "s " + randNum(0, 0.7) + "s linear infinite";
}
```